# How to read files from folder, which are outside the WEB-INF folder?

Tags: java

I have a Web Application project in java. If I deploy that project, then the project has on the Tomcat server at folder level a structure as follows:

-conf
-image
-META-INF
-profiles
-WEB-INF

I want to read some files from the folder "profiles" and "config". I tried using

```java
Properties prop = new Properties();
try{
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("../webapps/WebApplicatioProject/profiles/file_001.properties"));
} catch (Exception e){
   logger.error(e.getClass().getName());
}
```

it did not work. Then I tried with

```java
Properties prop = new Properties();
try{
    prop.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../../../../profiles/fille_001.properties"));
} catch (Exception e){
    logger.error(e.getClass().getName());
}
```

it did not work also.

How can you read files from folder "profiles" and "conf", which are outside the WEB-INF folder?

Comment: Dont put server files outside of the WEB-INF, as the user can simply type WEBCONTEXT/conf to read the file in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

if the file is under WebContext folder we get by calling ServletContext object reference.

```
Properties props=new Properties();
    props.load(this.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/mesdata/"+fileName+".properties"));
```

if the file is under class path by using class loaders we can get the file location

```
Properties props=new Properties();
    props.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/com/raj/pkg/"+fileName+".properties"));
```

Answer (score 1):

As Stefan said, don't put them out WEB-INF/... so put them into WEB-INF/ and then read them in this way:

```java
ResourceBundle resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("fille_001");
```

Now you can access the properties inside fille_001.properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ServletContext.getResource` (or `getResourceAsStream`) to access resources using paths relative to the web application (including but not limited to those under `WEB-INF`).

```
InputStream in = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/profiles/fille_001.properties");
if(in != null) {
  try {
    prop.load(in);
  } finally {
    in.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really must, you can reverse engineer the location. Catch a FileNotFoundException before you catch the generic Exception and log File.getPath(), this puts out the absolute filename, you should be able to see form which directory the relative paths are derived from.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ServletContext.getResource`. `getResourceAsStream` works locally for me but fails in Jenkins.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("../../profiles/fille_001.properties")
```

Basically Classloader starts to look resources into `Web-Inf/classes` folder. So by giving relative path we can access location outside of `web-inf` folder.